# Creating a minimal sufficient statistic with Likelihood function

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

To find a *minimal sufficient statistic* you can take the likelihood ratio and find a function $T$ so that the ratio does not depend on the parameter $\theta$
, as page 18 here http://sites.stat.psu.edu/~mga/514/Ch6.pdf does it.

Since I do not understand the proof, I wonder if I can understand this via some logic or intuition.

Comment: In which direction are you having problems? I would have thought it was intuitive that if $T(X)$ partitions $\mathcal{X}$ then you want the likelihood ratio to depend on $\theta$ if and only if $X$ and $Y$ are in different partitions

Comment: I'm not a student anymore.